# PMD violation for writing to the System.err stream at application startup

Tags: java, pmd

I get a PMD violation for using `System.err.println` in my Java project which is quite valid. However, this is used in the `main()` method of the application to check and fail-fast on the event of wrong arguments passed at the application start.

What best practices driven approach can I use here that let's me write to the error stream in case the application is supplied with inaccurate arguments and, keep PMD happy as well?

Comment: Use a proper logger.

Comment: Alternatively, exclude this code from PMD checks (suppress the warning).